# parsing owl file

Tags: java

Thanks for the previous posts. That helped a lot in parsing the owl file. Please look at the following code.

```
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

        OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();

        File file = new File("sample.owl");

        OWLOntology localOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
        System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + localOntology);

        IRI documentIRI = manager.getOntologyDocumentIRI(localOntology);
        System.out.println("    from: " + documentIRI);


        OWLClass clsAMethodA = factory.getOWLClass(documentIRI);
```

The examples stated in the documentation of owl uses IRI that right now doesnot exists. I am not understanding how do i extract all classes of the owl file. Where should i save the classes. How do i go about in saving those classes?? Any help?

Comment: someone please post your thoughts..i really need it..

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the OWL API and then follow a code like mine. I am getting all the logical axioms. From axioms, you can extract other modelling elements such as classes and individuals.

```
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLOntology localOntology=null;

    File file=new File("ontology/pizza.owl");
    if (file == null)
        return;

    //loading the ontology
    try {
        localOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
    } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


            //get logical axioms
    Set<OWLLogicalAxiom> ax = localOntology.getLogicalAxioms();
```